# Why the differential equation ${dx \over dt}= \sqrt x, x(0)=0 $ has infinitely many solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I show that the differential equation:

> $${dx \over dt }=\sqrt x, x(0)=0$$

has infinitely many solutions.

One solution will be $x={t^2 \over 4}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k$ be a positive real number. Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by:
$f(t)=0$ if $t<k$, and $f(t)=\frac{(t-k)^{2}}{4}$ for $t>k$. Now check that:

- $f'(t)=\sqrt{f(t)}$ for all $t$
- $f(0)=0$
- $f$ is continuously differentiable at $t=k$ (at all other points this is obvious)